# Oracle Weblogic Server Client Error Message Supress or Restrict

Tags: oracle, exception, error-handling, weblogic, jax-rpc

I would like to restrict client side error message on Weblogic.
I havent found any solution on it. In that image, would like to suppress bea_fault:stacktrace part.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have not explicitly specified which web service technology you are using. I guess that is jax-rpc.

So, i think, you can solve by following ways.

By editing web.xml, you can get response message. ExceptionHandler must be implements javax.servlet.Filter.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ExceptionHandler</filter-name>
    <filter-class>ExceptionHandler</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ExceptionHandler</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```